# Low resolution Image jspdf and Html2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

We are creating pdf with the help of jsPDF and HTML2canvas. But image resolution is bit high.

Is there any way to get low-resolution image with jquery, javascript, jsPDF and html2canvas

```
function addElement(element, doc, opt, newPage, callback) {
        var thiscreen = element;
        //Get the original background color.
        var originalBGColor = thiscreen.style.backgroundColor;
        //Change the background color of the element to desired color.
        if (opt.bgColor)
            thiscreen.style.backgroundColor = opt.bgColor;
        var options = options || {};
        options.elements = [thiscreen];
        //Increment the in-progress counter.
        counter++;
        console.log('adding' + counter);
        console.log(element);
        //The complete callback method.
        options.complete = setTimeout(function(images) {
            //Decrement the in-progress counter since the image is successfully generated..
            counter--;
            console.log('complete' + counter);
            console.log(element);
            var queue = html2canvas.Parse(thiscreen, images, options),
                canvas = html2canvas.Renderer(queue, options);
            //Reset the background color.
            thiscreen.style.backgroundColor = originalBGColor;
            //Add the generated image to PDF document.
            doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL(), 'png', opt.x, opt.y, opt.width, opt.height);
            //Call the callback method if any
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }, 500);
        //Conver the html to PNG using html2canvas util.
        html2canvas.Preload(thiscreen, options);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of an image can be reduced using any tool but reducing using jquery may not be easier.
Try reducing the image size using tools and refer.
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-asynchronously-loading-image